# how to aggregate multi tasks progress in a nsprogressindicator

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have many tasks.
these talks have progress value from 1 to 100. 
how to aggregate these progresses in a NSProgressIndicator?

for example: task1 values (these values created by other framework)
1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8......100.
there are a lot numbers duplication.

Comment: Add them all up and divide by the number of tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found I can use NSProgress to resolve my question.